# Javascript/Jquery - Calculate values and show inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calculator

I've got to write it down a scheme to show you what I am trying to develop. As you can see in the image below, there is a radio and a select area. Depending on the users choice on both areas there will be different values to consider in the function. The red values are related to the dropdown list. If you choose the op1 and "a" on the dropdown, "a" will be 2160. If you choose op3 and "c" on the dropdown, "c" will be 3888 and so on. The total will be shown inside the #total div and the values related to the choice on the radio and the dropdown will be shown inside other two divs #subRadio and #subDrop (the value that is been added to the radio value).

When I tried to solve it I end up with a huge list of if's that actually didn't worked at all, so I ask you guys your help on this problem.

[image: instructions]

Just in case anyone ask, I'll put here the code I started to write:

```
<form class="form-horizontal text-left" id="meishi">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-2 topic">
      <label>Design</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="design" value="10800">op1
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="design" value="14040">op2
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="design" value="16200">op3
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2" for="qtt">Quantity</label>
    <select id="qtt" class="col-lg-3" name="qtt">
      <option value="">Choose one</option>
      <option value="a">100</option>
      <option value="b">200</option>
      <option value="c">300</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>


$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#msQtt").change(function(){
    var design = $('input[name=design]:checked').val();
    var qtt = $("#qtt option:selected").val();
    if(design  == "10800" && qtt == "a"){
      $('#subRadio').text('$ 10800')
      $('#subDrop').text('$ 2160')
      $('#total').text('$ 12960')
    }
    else if(design  == "10800" && qtt == "b"){
      $('#subRadio').text('$ 10800')
      $('#subDrop').text('$ 2484')
      $('#total').text('$ 13284')
    }
  });
});
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Add the markup as well

Comment: use parseInt() function and set condition

Comment: @FelipeFelixdeLuca I can't see any formula in your code :/

Comment: Where is `#msQtt' in the markup ?

Comment: Can the red values be calculated, or are the fixed?

Comment: @Vixed, I'm just starting to write my own codes, so I don't think the code I have wrote does some help :/ I'll appreciate all the help tho :)

Comment: What are the red numbers? They seem to have a relation with the black, but can't seem to get the exact relation.

Comment: @Mayank, Sorry, I edited before posting it here. It should be the select area's ID!

Comment: LinkinTED and @Parth, the red ones are related to the dropdown list. If you choose the op1 and "a" on the dropdown, "a" will be 2160. If you choose op3 and "c" on the dropdown, "c" will be 3888 and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope that's what are you looking for **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/9cnkfoa8/)**

```
<form class="form-horizontal text-left" id="meishi">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-2 topic">
      <label>Design</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" data-drop-a="2160" data-drop-b="2484" data-drop-c="2808" name="design" value="10800">op1
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" data-drop-a="2808" data-drop-b="3132" data-drop-c="3456" name="design" value="14040">op2
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" data-drop-a="3240" data-drop-b="3564" data-drop-c="3888" name="design" value="16200">op3
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2" for="qtt">Quantity</label>
    <select id="qtt" class="col-lg-3" name="qtt">
      <option value="">Choose one</option>
      <option value="a">100</option>
      <option value="b">200</option>
      <option value="c">300</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

_

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input[name=design], #qtt").on('change',function(){
    var design = $('input[name=design]:checked');
    var designVal = parseInt(design.val());
    var qtt = $("#qtt").val();
    var subDrop=parseInt(design.data('drop-'+qtt));
    if (!subDrop) subDrop=0;
    if (!designVal) designVal=0;
    $('#subRadio').text(designVal)
    $('#subDrop').text(subDrop)
    $('#total').text(designVal+subDrop)
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you @Vixed! I'll try it here as well!

Comment: my form is inside a modal, so If the user closes the modal all the information selected before keeps selected. Do you know how can I clean the selected areas by clicking the exit button?

Comment: I'm sorry @FelipeFelixdeLuca, but I need a bit of code to see what you need.

Comment: I updated my page in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/felipefelixluca/j8haLd2z/7/). Thank you again!

Comment: I found a way to clean the form, but I don't know why my second form is not working. I used your code as reference and changed the variables. The base is the same so, I don't get the error. Can you take a look for me? It is my fiddle in my previous comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Create an object where your store your data:

```
var data = {
    'opt10800' : {
    'a' : 2160 ,
    'b' : 2484 ,
    'c' : 2808
  },
    'opt14040' : {
    'a' : 2808 ,
    'b' : 3132 ,
    'c' : 3456
  },
    'opt16200':  {
    'a' : 3240 ,
    'b' : 3564 ,
    'c' : 3888
  }
};
```

Then, when either the dropdown or radio buttons are changed, take the values from the object and put them inside the spans:

```
$(function() {
  $('[name=design],[name=qtt]').on('change', function() {
    var r = $('[name=design]:checked').val() ,
        d = $('[name=qtt] option:selected').val();
    if( r != '' && d != '') {
      var s = data['opt'+r][d] ,
          t = parseInt( r ) + parseInt( s );
      $('#subRadio').text( r + ' + ' );
      $('#subDrop').text( s + ' = ' );
      $('#total').text( t );
    }
  });
});
```

**Full demo:**

```js
var data = {
 'opt10800' : {
   'a' : 2160 ,
    'b' : 2484 ,
    'c' : 2808
  },
 'opt14040' : {
   'a' : 2808 ,
    'b' : 3132 ,
    'c' : 3456
  },
 'opt16200':  {
   'a' : 3240 ,
    'b' : 3564 ,
    'c' : 3888
  }
};


$(function() {
  $('[name=design],[name=qtt]').on('change', function() {
    var r = $('[name=design]:checked').val() ,
        d = $('[name=qtt] option:selected').val();
    if( r != '' && d != '') {
      var s = data['opt'+r][d] ,
          t = parseInt( r ) + parseInt( s );
      $('#subRadio').text( r + ' + ' );
      $('#subDrop').text( s + ' = ' );
      $('#total').text( t );
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal text-left" id="meishi">
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-lg-2 topic">
      <label>Design</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="design" value="10800">op1
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="design" value="14040">op2
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <label class="radio-inline">
        <input type="radio" name="design" value="16200">op3
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-lg-2" for="qtt">Quantity</label>
    <select id="qtt" class="col-lg-3" name="qtt">
      <option value="">Choose one</option>
      <option value="a">100</option>
      <option value="b">200</option>
      <option value="c">300</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
<span id="subRadio"></span>
<span id="subDrop"></span>
<span id="total"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the working [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rv0y8907/3/)

Updated javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function UpdatePrice() {
    var CalMatrix = [{
        val1: 10800,
        val2: 'a',
        resultant: 2160
      }, {
        val1: 10800,
        val2: 'b',
        resultant: 2484
      }, {
        val1: 10800,
        val2: 'c',
        resultant: 2808
      },

      {
        val1: 14040,
        val2: 'a',
        resultant: 2808
      }, {
        val1: 14040,
        val2: 'b',
        resultant: 3132
      }, {
        val1: 14040,
        val2: 'c',
        resultant: 3456
      },

      {
        val1: 16200,
        val2: 'a',
        resultant: 3240
      }, {
        val1: 16200,
        val2: 'b',
        resultant: 3564
      }, {
        val1: 16200,
        val2: 'c',
        resultant: 3888
      }

    ];
    var design = $('input[name=design]:checked').val();
    var qtt = $("#qtt option:selected").val();

    var result = $.grep(CalMatrix, function(n) {
      return Number(n.val1) == Number(design) && n.val2 == qtt;
    });

    $('#subRadio').html('$ ' + String(result[0].val1))
    $('#subDrop').html('$ ' + String(result[0].resultant))
    $('#total').html('$ ' + parseInt(result[0].val1 + result[0].resultant, 10));
  }

  $('#qtt').on('change', function(e) {
    UpdatePrice(); // to calculate the price on change event
  });

UpdatePrice(); // to calculate the price on page load
});
```

**Edit**

Updated [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rv0y8907/4/),

Attached a new handler on radio change event too

```
$('#qtt, input[type=radio][name=design]').on('change', function(e) {
    UpdatePrice(); // to calculate the price on change event
});
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thank you @Mayank! I'll test it here :D

Comment: looking through Fiddle, I found something strange. The value of "design" only updates if I change the quantity on the drop-list. Was it suppose to react that way from the beginning? Thank you again for you time!